# The first derivative of complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I want to find the first derivative of $\frac{\mathrm{d} f(z)}{\mathrm{d} z}$ with $z = x+ iy$.

For a simple example, what is $\frac{\mathrm{d} z^* }{\mathrm{d} z}$ with $z^* = x - iy$?

Thank you very much!

P/S:This question may be trivial but I did not take the complex analysis course.

Comment: Not all functions of complex argument are differentiable. Those that are, satisfy [Cauchy-Riemann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations) conditions. For example, $f(z) = \bar z$ is not differentiable anywhere.

Comment: @Hathanhminh  - I suggest trying to differentiate $z^n$ for $n \geq 1$ to get used to complex derivatives.

Comment: @muaddib Please tell something more. It is what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One can prove that if $f(x+iy) = u(x,y) + i v(x,y)$ is differentiable, then the Cauchy-Riemann equations must hold: $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}, \quad \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}.$$And if this is the case: $$\frac{{\rm d}f}{{\rm d}z} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}.$$Use this to check that $f(z) = \overline{z}$ is **not** differentiable (the CR equations fail).

Comment: It means that $f(z) = |z|^2$ is not differentiable, right? this is because $|z|^2 = zz^{*}$